# jquery accordion avoid indentation

Tags: html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I need a Jquery UI multi-level accordion.
I have tested it with the following markup, but I need to get rid of the indentation for each level.
Is this possible? (The "accordion" class contains nothing, it is just for selection)

I have included an illustration of the (red) areas that I need to remove.

[image]

```
<div id="faqs-container" class="accordion">
        <h3><a href="#">One</a></h3>

        <div class="accordion">
            <h3><a class="" href="#">A</a></h3>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>list</li>
                    <li>list</li>
                    <li>list</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <h3><a href="#">B</a></h3>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>list</li>
                    <li>list</li>
                    <li>list</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h3><a href="#">Two</a></h3>
        <div>
            <-- A Wrapper -->
         <ul>
             <li>But They</li>
             <li>Do Not</li>
             <li>Work</li>
         </ul>
            <div class="accordion">
                <h3><a href="#">A2</a></h3>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>list</li>
                        <li>list</li>
                        <li>list</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <h3><a href="#">B2</a></h3>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>list</li>
                        <li>list</li>
                        <li>list</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: this is the default style for `jquery-ui-accordion` i guess

Comment: give custom class and customize style for nested accordion

Comment: Ok, I did try to figure out which styles affect this prior to asking, but no luck.
So I guess answering the question involves knowing what styling is needed

Answer (score 0):

I found the styling needed here: 
[Jquery Forum](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/accordion-change-left-margin-for-content)

I inserted this styling and it removed the horizontal indentation.

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content {
    padding: 1em 0;
}
```